# Nested request not succeeding while using nock

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, nock

I have defined the following simple function and I want to test this using nock.

```
function checkJobAndUpload(ycgResponse, targetJob, integrationId, jobBoardId, callback) {
    const options = {
        uri: 'https://multiposting.stepstone.com/status/1',
        method: 'GET',
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    };
    const payload = JSON.stringify({ message: 'success' })
    const put_options = {
        uri: 'https://multiposting.stepstone.com/listings/1',
        method: 'PUT',
        body: payload,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    };
    rp(options).then(response => {
        console.log('Status call succeeded')
        return rp(put_options)
    }).then(response => {
        console.log('Update call succeeded')
        callback(null, { statusCode: 200 });
    }).catch(error => {
        callback({ statusCode: 500 });
    });
}
```

Below is my nock setup.

```
it('Should succeed in check, update and upload job status functions', () => {
    nock.cleanAll();
    var statusAPI = nock('https://multiposting.stepstone.com').get(`/status/1`).reply(200, statusResponse)
    var putAPI = nock('https://multiposting.stepstone.com/').filteringRequestBody(function (body) {
        console.log(body);
        return 'ABC';
    }).put('/listings/1', 'ABC').reply(201)
    console.log(nock.pendingMocks())
    sut.checkAndUpload(ycgResponse, targetJob, integrationId, jobBoard, function (err, response) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log('----')
        console.log(response)
        console.log(nock.activeMocks())
        console.log(putAPI.isDone())
        console.log(statusAPI.isDone())
        should.equal(200, response.statusCode)
    });
});
```

The issue here is that the `callback` is not being called back. Always the first `GET` request passes but the `PUT` request neither passes nor fails. I do not see any errors as well.

Here is my `console.logs`

```
uploader
    #check and upload
[ 'GET https://multiposting.stepstone.com:443/status/1',
  'PUT https://multiposting.stepstone.com:443/listings/1' ]
      ✓ Should succeed in check, update and upload job status functions
Status call succeeded
{"message":"success"}
  1 passing (32ms)
```

Comment: Note that SO doesn't use GitHub-flavoured markdown, you need to indent code blocks not "fence" them.

Comment: I will do it the right way next time. Thanks for the info!